# pick data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL.

My question is how to make a filter like amazon product.

I made a matrimony site with filter. I wrote a query to access data from multiple tables. I give foreign key to another table link. When I run query it hangs the computer.

I know my way is bogus but I don't know how to solve it. So please help me by your computer mind.

My code is:

```
SELECT
  U1.id,
  U1.name,
  U1.day,
  U1.month,
  U1.year,
  U1.email,
  U1.country_code,
  U1.number,
  U2.rname,
  U3.gname,
  U4.mtname,
  U5.country,
  U6.sub_community,
  U7.mstatus,
  U8.state,
  U9.city,
  U10.name,
  U12.hname,
  U13.sname,
  U14.name,
  U15.name,
  U16.name,
  U17.food
FROM
  userprofile1 as U1
  JOIN religion as U2
    ON U1.Relegion=U2.reid
  JOIN gender as U3
    ON U1.ugender=U3.g_id
  JOIN mother_tongue as U4
    ON U1.mother_tongue=U4.mt_id
  JOIN country as U5
    ON U1.country=U5.country_id
  JOIN  userprofile2 as U6
    ON U1.id=U6.f_id1
  JOIN maritialstatus as U7
    ON U6.maritial_status=U7.id
  JOIN state as U8
    ON U6.state=U8.state_id
  JOIN city as U9
    ON U6.city=U9.city_id
  JOIN community as U10
    ON U6.ucommunity=U10.id
  JOIN userprofile3 as U11
    ON U6.1id=U11.f_id2
  JOIN height as U12
    ON U11.uheight=U12.h_id
  JOIN skin as U13
    ON U11.uskin=U13.s_id
  JOIN smoke as U14
    ON U11.usmoke=U14.sm_id
  JOIN drink as U15
    ON U11.udrink=U15.d_id  
  JOIN body as U16
    ON U11.ubody=U16.b_id  
  JOIN food as U17
    ON U11.ufood=U17.id     
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not very huge, the query should not go for infinite time.
You can add all these joins one by one and check which join is actually creating a problem. Remove those joins and hence reduce your execution time.
Further you can use the search using the input keyword by concatenating all the fields and using locate function for the search keyword.

Example:

```
WHERE LOCATE(keyword,col1+col2+col3+....) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

"Over-normalization".  For example, instead of having a separate table for 'smoke', use

```
ENUM('decline to state', 'smoker', 'non-smoker')
```

or something like that.  It is compact, simple, faster, etc.

```
ENUM('decline to state', 'married', 'single', 'divorced', 'separated', ...)

ENUM('decline to state', 'male', 'female', 'trans', ...)
```

The standard 2-letter country codes are fine for using without a separate table.  Ditto for 2-letter 'state' (assuming you are thinking US states).

'Continuous' things (eg, height) should never be normalized.  Have your app convert to inches (or whatever you like) and store into `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or `FLOAT`.

As for locating a keyword in multiple columns, it would be better to add a new column and toss everything into it that you want to search on.  Then make a `FULLTEXT` index on that column and use `MATCH...AGAINST`.  (Be sure to read and understand the limitations of `FULLTEXT`.)

The issues with `WHERE LOCATE(keyword,col1+col2+col3+....) >= 0`

- `+` is not `CONCAT`
- It is slow (but maybe that is ok if there is limited data)
- It has no concept of word boundaries